# nginx how do I force a redirect to a named block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up nginx so that it will server all my static files directly, but the api calls redirect to a backend node app.  Previously this app served the static files as well, but I am trying to change it not to do that.

So I have a few very specific urls that I want redirecting to my backend.

I have created a named block with what I think are all the required parameters

```
location @api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2020;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

but how do I redirect to it.  I tried

```
  location /api/ {
    try_files @api;
  }

  location = /logon {
    try_files @api;
  }

  location = /logoff {
    try_files @api;
  }
```

as this was the only reference to named locations that I could find, but `nginx` doesn't like `try_files` without at least one file to try.  Of course the backend needs to know the original url that was passed, so it can route properly.  Does `proxy_pass` do that?, but it also means that I can't redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try_files` to invoke to a named location immediately by placing a non-existent filename as the first parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
try_files nonexistent @api;
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression `location` in place of the named location block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(api/|log(in|off)$) { proxy_pass ...; ... }
```

---

The most efficient solution is to place the proxy configuration into a separate file and use `include` to pull it into your three `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.

Comment: I had used the regular expression block as a temporary solution to my problem.  So I think that is the way to go - shame there is no better way.  I was debating to use include, but I am using a symlink from `sites-available` into my development directory and I want to minimise reference to long user specific directory strings..